# Perl convert JSON format into Comma separated values

Tags: json, perl, csv

I am using web service that print output in JSON format as below,

```
{
  'message' => '',
  'data' => [
              {
                'name' => 'Lee calls',
                'empid' => '1289328',
                'desc_id' => 'descl23423..23431'
              },
              {
                'name' => 'Lee calls',
                'empid' => '23431223',
                'desc_id' => 'descl23423..234324'
              }
            ],
  'status' => 'success'
};
```

I just need to convert the 'Data' item values into a CSV format. The need is, i have to create perl file which will be executed in the CLI(Command line interface) or a Linux terminal. So the perl will pull content from the Webservice and have to convert the JSON output into CSV format.

Can you suggest me on this how to do?

Comment: that's not JSON

Comment: Do you have an idea about how you would like to represent that JSON in CSV? There is no general way to represent nested data structures in CSV, and you will have to specify something. It may help if you explained more about the background to your problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What Perl modules have you looked at for example, and why weren't they adequate for your task?

Comment: @ Borodin. Thank you! Updated my question.

Comment: yes, that isn't JSON, it is dumped perl data.  eval() in perl will turn it back into a datastructure

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) to read JSON strings into Perl data structures. Then, use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) to create the output in CSV format:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $json = '[ {
                "name" : "Lee calls",
                "empid" : "1289328",
                "desc_id" : "descl23423..23431"
              },
              {
                "name" : "Lee calls",
                "empid" : "23431223",
                "desc_id" : "descl23423..234324"
              } ]';
my $struct = decode_json($json);

my $csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({ binary => 1, eol => "\n" });
open my $OUT, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'output.csv' or die $!;
$csv->print($OUT, [ @$_{qw{ name empid desc_id }} ]) for @$struct;
close $OUT or die $!;
```